# Discordl API: Как упомянуть канал через вебхук

Tags: discord

Подскажите пожалуйста как упомянуть канал через вебхук в дискорде.

Comment: получилось найти способ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<#ID>
```

Где ID - это ID упоминаемого канала.

Пример:

```
<#905772737077837865>
```